# Magento 2 How to get serialized data and use in Dropdown Box

Tags: magento2, checkout, dynamic-rows

I am using Dynamic Rows in a module that saves data to the core_config_data table like this:

```
{"_1564763325005_5":{"addresses":"123 My Street, Bldg. 1, Reno, NV 85234"},"_1566830530708_708":{"addresses":"2123 My Street 2, Bldg 2, Reno, NV, 12345"}}
```

I am using this to take values and populate a dropdown box in a form that was built for checkout:

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Options
{
    protected $arrayManager;

    public function __construct( ArrayManager $arrayManager )
    {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $checkoutBuildingAddressOptionsPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(
                'checkout_building_address',
                $jsLayout
            ).'/options';
        return $this->arrayManager->set(
            $checkoutBuildingAddressOptionsPath,
            $jsLayout,
            $this->getCustomOptions()
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */

    protected function getCustomOptions(): array
    {
        // TODO:: get it from somewhere
        $options = [
            [
                'value' => '1',
                'label' => 'This is the first option',
            ],
            [
                'value' => '2',
                'label' => 'Opt 2',
            ],
            [
                'value' => '3',
                'label' => 'Opt 3',
            ],
            [
                'value' => '4',
                'label' => 'Opt 4',
            ],
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time getting the data from the table into the $options array.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what made it work:

```
protected function getCustomOptions(): array
    {
      // used $json as a test to see if it works
      $json = "{\"_1564763325005_5\":{\"addresses\":\"123 My Street, Bldg. 1, Palm Springs, CA 92234\"},\"_1566830530708_708\":{\"addresses\":\"2123 My Street, Bldg 23, Reno, NV, 12345\"}}";
      $arrayResult = json_decode($json, true);
      $options = [];

      foreach ($arrayResult as $item) {
        $options[] = [
        'value' => $item['addresses'],
        'label' => $item['addresses']
        ];
      }

      return $options;
    }
```

Now my options are populated from the core_config_data table from items created using dynamic rows.